# Certificate has expired?

Tags: ios, macos, titanium, appcelerator-titanium

When am running my old apps in simulator and ios device am getting below error.

When I run the newly created sample apps in simulator it is working fine without any problem.

```
**Error:**

[ERROR] : certificate has expired
2017-10-14T05:46:30.298Z | TRACE | titanium exited with exit code 100
2017-10-14T05:46:30.299Z | ERROR | Error: ti run exited with error code 100
at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/balakrishna/.appcelerator/install/5.1.0/package/node_modules/appc-cli-titanium/plugins/run.js:92:66)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1074:12)
2017-10-14T05:46:30.300Z | TRACE | Sending exit signal to titanium process: 2240
```

My System Specifications:

```
    Appcelerator Command-Line version = 5.1.0
    Operating System                   = Mac OS X 10.11.4 - 64bit
    Node.js Version                   = 0.12.7
    Npm Version                       = 2.11.3
    Titanium CLI Version              = 5.0.5
    Titanium SDK Version              = 5.2.2.GA
    Appcelerator Studio               = 4.4.0
```

I have valid distributed certificate and provisioning profiles. How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error, though switching my logs to Trace level includes an additional line:

```
[TRACE] :  result from /build-verify=> {"success":false,"error":"certificate has expired","code":"com.appcelerator.security.invalid.module.verification"}, err=null
[ERROR] :  certificate has expired
```

com.appcelerator.security.invalid.module.verification. in my case it was the google amalytics module causing the error.

I removed all but google analytics from my project, assuming it to be the most stable, tried to build and it still failed with the same certificate error.

Removed analytics and rebuilt; App built fine and obviously errored when it got to a point where it needed to use one of the modules.

I then re-added all modules except analytics and rebuilt; Built fine. THEN i added analytics back in...and it built fine.

So i'm not sure what haphazard certificate issues the IDE has, but removed all modules, rebuilding and then adding them back in seemed to fix the issue.

For reference other modules I had in use were: bencoding.blur, ti.compression and com.factisresearch.html2pdf